# change elgg php function to javascript function

Tags: javascript, php, function, time, elgg

change elgg_get_friendly_time to javascript

I strucked in this `$params = array('time' => $time);` and `return elgg_echo("friendlytime:justnow");`

```
<?php

function elgg_get_friendly_time($time) {

// return a time string to short circuit normal time formatting
$params = array('time' => $time);
$result = elgg_trigger_plugin_hook('format', 'friendly:time', $params, NULL);
if ($result) {
return $result;
}

$diff = time() - (int)$time;

$minute = 60;
$hour = $minute * 60;
$day = $hour * 24;

if ($diff < $minute) {
return elgg_echo("friendlytime:justnow");
} else if ($diff < $hour) {
$diff = round($diff / $minute);
if ($diff == 0) {
$diff = 1;
}

if ($diff > 1) {
return elgg_echo("friendlytime:minutes", array($diff));
} else {
return elgg_echo("friendlytime:minutes:singular", array($diff));
}
} else if ($diff < $day) {
$diff = round($diff / $hour);
if ($diff == 0) {
$diff = 1;
}

if ($diff > 1) {
return elgg_echo("friendlytime:hours", array($diff));
} else {
return elgg_echo("friendlytime:hours:singular", array($diff));
}
} else {
$diff = round($diff / $day);
if ($diff == 0) {
$diff = 1;
}

if ($diff > 1) {
return elgg_echo("friendlytime:days", array(diff));
} else {
return elgg_echo("friendlytime:days:singular", array($diff));
}
}
}

?>
```

Comment: Something tells me you really should look at using DateTime for this...

Answer (score 0):

I looked up the docs for the function:

http://reference.elgg.org/engine_2lib_2output_8php.html#aa008ab7b454c680f83ca7a62409c6ab5

and it reminded me I have some JS code that does something similar, which might help you:

```
function get_friendly_date(date) {
    var now = new Date();
    var diff = Math.floor((now - date) / 1000); // seconds
    var min = 60;           // seconds
    var hour = 3600;        // seconds
    var day = 86400;        // seconds
    var month = 30.5 * day; // seconds
    months = Math.floor(diff / month);
    if (months >= 1) return months + " months ago";
    else {
        days = Math.floor(diff / day);
        if (days == 1) return days + " day ago";
        else if (days > 1) return days + " days ago";
        else {
            hours = Math.floor(diff / hour);
            if (hours == 1) return hours + " hour ago"
            else if (hours > 1) return hours + " hours ago";
            else {
                mins = Math.floor(diff / min);
                if (mins == 1) return mins + " min ago";
                else if (mins > 1) return mins + " mins ago";
                else {
                    return diff + " seconds ago";
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

which I put in a fiddle, that you can play around with here:

http://jsfiddle.net/hM2LU/

Hope that helps!